# MuleStudio - Failed to Deploy application

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am having trouble starting a Mule application from MuleStudio. Any pointers?

Here is my Configuration xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.4.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http: //www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http: //www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http: //www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http: //www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="testing" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

.... here is the exception I am getting

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Initializing app 'test'                                  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2014-05-25 16:48:56,694 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'test' never started, nothing to dispose of
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy application [test]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:61)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:58)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:91)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.config.DefaultMuleConfiguration.validateXML(DefaultMuleConfiguration.java:371)
    at org.mule.config.DefaultMuleConfiguration.<init>(DefaultMuleConfiguration.java:209)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.ApplicationMuleContextBuilder.createMuleConfiguration(ApplicationMuleContextBuilder.java:36)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextBuilder.getMuleConfiguration(DefaultMuleContextBuilder.java:135)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextBuilder.buildMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextBuilder.java:97)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.buildMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:215)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:201)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:79)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:207)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Please give your full Mule configuration ... It is difficult to analyze from just 2 lines of code

Comment: All the config was here but the OP didn't bother using code formatting. Fixed.